# Jemand, der etwas empfiehlt, ist ein …?

Tags: single-word-request

Auf Englisch ist jemand, der etwas empfiehlt, ein *recommender* (obwohl das Wort recht selten ist). Auf Deutsch scheint das Wort *Empfehler* nicht zu existieren (z.B. Duden und dict.leo.org kennen das Wort nicht), obwohl es für mich (als Ausländer) sehr logisch erscheint. Wie nennt man jemanden, der etwas für jemanden anderen empfiehlt?

Comment: Willkommen im StackExchange der Deutschen Sprache. Falls Du mehr wissen möchtest, kannst Du Dir die [tour] anschauen oder einen Blick ins [help] werfen. Viel Vergnügen!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ein Tippgeber, ein Gewährsmann, ein Ratgeber, ein Berater, ein Empfehler oder Empfehlungsgeber.

Der Tippgeber ist eher informell, während der Berater eher in den professionellen Bereich gehört. Der Gewährsmann ist eher da, wo es auf Vertrauen ankommt, anzutreffen ("Ich brauche einen guten Pass; mein Gewährsmann Smollerbeck hat Sie empfohlen.").

Comment: Tippgeber sagt kein Mensch.

Comment: @äüö: Du warst lang nicht mehr auf der Rennbahn, wa? Oder Krimis geschaut? Politdramas über Whistleblower?

Comment: Tippgeber klingt wie Essenmacher anstelle von Koch ;)

Comment: Für Dich, @äüö, nur für Dich.

Comment: und für den Rest der Welt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tippgeber%2CRatgeber&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTippgeber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRatgeber%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Oder: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tippgeber%2CTipgeber&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTippgeber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTipgeber%3B%2Cc0 Dass Ratgeberbücher eine Seuche sind wussten wir ja vorher.

Comment: Wie ich schon andeutete (und per Downvote unterstreiche), alle Formen von Tippgeber sind gegen Ratgeber verschwindend klein (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tippgeber%2CTipgeber%2CRatgeber&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTippgeber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTipgeber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRatgeber%3B%2Cc0 ), aber du stellst es in deiner Antwort als den ersten Punkt deiner Aufzählung dar, so dass sich ein Zerrbild ergibt, da die Leute denken, dass Tippgeber deswegen superwichtig wäre. Geh also besser auf die Häufigkeiten in deiner Antwort ein.

Comment: Die Frage dreht sich nicht um Häufigkeiten und wenn Du meinst, die Reihenfolge impliziere eine Häufigkeit ist das Dein Problem. Deine erste Kritik war, dass kein Mensch Tippgeber sagt - offenbar ist diese Aussage falsch.

Comment: Nein, nicht falsch, siehe Nulllinie bei ngram. In der Antwort also nicht den Ausnahmefall zuerst ansagen. Ich drehe mich hier gerade im Kreis. Darum beende ich das jetzt. Message ist eigentlich klar. Mach was daraus (oder auch nicht).

Comment: Doch falsch, denn die Nulllinie ist ja eine Näherung. Das siehst Du ja an meinem Link. Zweitens misst es nur Bücher, keine Zeitschriften, Zeitungen, Briefe, mündliche Rede, usw. Drittens hängt es vom Kontext ab, was man lieber sagt - was die Mehrheit der Bücher sagt ist nicht normativ.

Comment: @äöü Ich frage mich auch, woher du wissen willst, wie alle Menschen reden...

Comment: Das Wort hat sogar einen Wikipedia-Eintrag...

Comment: Was soll diese unsinnige Diskussion? _Tippgeber_ habe ich auch schon gehört, _Empfehler_ hingegen nicht. Nichtsdestoweniger sind beides sagbare, verständliche Wörter. Will man Goethe – oder jedem anderen wortgewandten Schriftsteller – vorwerfen, er habe Wörter gebraucht, die kein Mensch zuvor gesagt hatte?

Answer (score 6):

Ich würde hier "Ratgeber" verwenden - das englische Gegenstück wäre zwar eher "advisor" als "recommender", aber "Empfehlungsgeber" hört sich nun wirklich nicht besonders gut an.

//edit: Nach einem Tipp von "Janek Bevendorff" passt "Berater" besser - "Ratgeber" ist eher eine Art Buch mit Ratschlägen.

Comment: Unter einem Ratgeber verstehe ich aber eher ein schlaues Buch. Der Begriff *Berater* passt hier besser.

Comment: stimmt, da hab ich nicht dran gedacht :) ich war durch "empfehlungsgeber" irgendwie verwirrt ^^

Comment: Hey und willkommen im StackExchange für die Deutsche Sprache. Wenn Du magst, kannst Du Dir die [tour] oder das [help] anschauen. Viel Erfolg!

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu danke für den tipp, aber das unterscheidet sich nicht wesentlich von stack overflow, von daher hab ich da garnicht weiter drauf geachtet :)

Comment: Sicher. Für SO/SE-pros ist die Mechanik nix neues, jedoch sind's oft die on-topic-Regelungen. Die sind von SE zu SE verschieden und finden sich im Helpcenter - als Einstiegsreferenz deshalb immer eine gute Idee. Im Zweifel hamwer natürlich noch unser eigenes Meta. :)

Comment: Wenn @JanekBevendorff dir eine Alternative empfohlen hat, war er dein **_Tippgeber_** (klassische Rechtschreibung: _Tipgeber_). Das wird allerdings auch für **_Informanten_** im kriminalistischen Sinne verwendet, ebenso **_Quelle_**.

Answer (score 5):

Wortwörtlich wäre es

> Der Empfehlende

Comment: Das wäre doch eher eine zeit- und situationsabhängige Szenenbeschreibung. Als absolute Beschreibung einer Person finde ich das falsch.

Comment: Meinem Sprachverständnis nach ist der Empfehlende tempusunabhängig als Gegenteil zum Empfehlungsempfänger zu verstehen. Situationsbedingt ist es sicherlich, aber einen absoluten Begriff, à la Empfehlungsgeber, gibt es nicht wirklich.

Answer (score 2):

Ein "Empfehlungsgeber". Dieses Wort wird jedoch selten verwendet. Man formuliert in der Regel so: "auf Empfehlung von ...".

Answer (score -1):

Empfehlungsgeber oder Ratgeber sind die mir gebräuchlichsten Begriffe.

Comment: People may not be too happy if you always post an answer that already exists, in this case it is the accepted and most upvoted answer. As soon as you have enough reputation points you will be able to contribute by upvoting such an answer. It is what we prefer. Please see the [tour] for more.

Comment: If, after registration you wish to merge your multiple accounts see https://german.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Takkat Die Auswahl der Begriffe, also das absichtliche Weglassen eines Teils der Begriffe der verlinkten Antwort bietet, meiner Meinung nach, schon einen Mehrwert und ist daher keine Dopplung der Antwort.